# UIView animation not showing

Tags: swift, animation

I'm trying to make an animation to where a view is created at a size of 10,10 and then spreads out to a larger scale. However, when i run the program, it shows the final width and height (where it should be after the animation) but doesn't show the animation itself. If anyone has any suggestions as to why that would be great thanks

```
@IBOutlet var PlayView: UIView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var yPos = (PlayView.frame.height/8)
    var xPos = (PlayView.frame.width/8)
    var tutView1=UIView(frame: CGRectMake(xPos, yPos, 10, 10))
    tutView1.backgroundColor=UIColor.lightGrayColor()
    tutView1.layer.cornerRadius=25
    tutView1.layer.borderWidth=2
    tutView1.layer.borderColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor().CGColor
    self.view.addSubview(tutView1)



    UIView.animateWithDuration(2.0, animations: {
        tutView1.frame = CGRect(x: xPos, y: yPos, width: 10+((xPos*6)-10), height: 10+((yPos*6)-10))


    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting this code inside the `viewDidAppear` instead.

Comment: No problem! The issue is that `viewDidLoad` gets called when the view is instantiated by the `ViewController`. This occurs before the view is displayed so your animations go off but are not visible so they complete by the time `viewDidAppear` goes off.